# Windows Phone 7 Page Transition

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any built-in way to reproduce the behaviour showed on the Office app, a 0:36 ? When the user tap the Shared Document item, a nice WP7-like transition makes it goes to the next page

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUZx8YHPlWM#t=0m36s

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034). It has a "Page Transition" control that does, I think, exactly what you want. It's a new feature in the November 2010 release.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks ! It worked, I followed the tutorial by Shawn Wildermuth http://wildermuth.com/2010/07/16/Bring_Back_Page_Transitions_to_the_Windows_Phone_List_Application_Template